# What is the difference between README and README.md in GitHub projects?

Tags: github, markdown

I've noticed some GitHub projects have not only a `README` file, but also a `README.md` file.

What is the difference between these files? I know `README` serves also as introductory text in the project repository page but I have no idea what `README.md` does.

Comment: I found this quick reference (cheatsheet) for markdown very useful:
[https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet)

Answer (score 404, accepted):

.md is [`markdown`](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).  `README.md` is used to generate the `html` summary you see at the bottom of projects.  Github has [their own flavor of Markdown](https://github.github.com/gfm/).

*Order of Preference:* If you have two files named `README` and `README.md`, the file named `README.md` is preferred, and it will be used to generate github's `html` summary.

---

FWIW, Stack Overflow [uses local Markdown modifications as well](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/10/15/markdown-one-year-later/) (also see [Stack Overflow's C# Markdown Processor](https://code.google.com/archive/p/markdownsharp))

Comment: Updated github markdown https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/

Comment: Excellent list of markdown features: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet

Answer (score 240):

`.md` stands for markdown and is generated at the bottom of your github page as html.

**Typical syntax includes:**

```
Will become a heading
==============

Will become a sub heading
--------------

*This will be Italic*

**This will be Bold**

- This will be a list item
- This will be a list item

    Add a indent and this will end up as code
```

**For more details:**
http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

Answer (score 37):

`.md` extension stands for Markdown, which Github uses, among others, to format those files.

Read about Markdown:

http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown

Also:

http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/

Answer (score 24):

`README.md` or `.mkdn` or `.markdown` denotes that the file is *markdown* formatted.
Markdown is a markup language. With it you can easily display headers or have italic words, or bold or almost anything that can be done to text