# What does the README.md file in git repo do?

Tags: git, github, readme

We have been using git repositories for projects. 
Also we download some code from there(Say sample code).

I found ReadMe.md file on each repository.

Why is it there? AND what is meaning of **.md**?

Also each folder contain that file some time. Why people add that file in git repository?

I don't have any idea, I want to know it as I started using git for code source management.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Github: README and README.md](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655937/github-readme-and-readme-md)

Comment: not really a duplicate

Comment: No i have searched that question already got some clue but not complete what I expect. The stack question you refer is about diff. But I want to know why about "readme.md" file.

Answer (score 20):

A Readme file is a file that describes the purpose of the repository and gives hints on what the code does, how to compile/use it, etc.

The `.md` extension stands for [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), which is a type of file that is both readable in plain text, but can also be easily converted to HTML to display special elements.

Stack Overflow happens to parse the same markdown syntax for questions and answers, so here are a few examples of what Markdown can do:

---

## Headings

[Links](http://google.com)

- Lists
- of
- items

---

The Markdown code I used on Stack Overflow to create those was:

```
# Headings

[Links](http://google.com)

* Lists
* of
* items
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the readme file provided by GitHub. And the file extension `.md` is the file extension for files that are processed as Markdown files.

[Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/) is the 'language' used by GitHub to render some particular styling.