# How do I use this PHP class in my code?

Tags: php

My directory structure:

```
bencode_test-
            |--> BEncode.php
            |--> bencode_test.php
            |--> ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent

my code:
    <?php
        require 'BEncode.php';
        $bcoder = new BEncode();
        $torrent = $bcoder->bdecode( File::get('ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent'));
        var_dump($torrent);
    ?>
```

I got BEncode.php from [this Github account](https://github.com/bhutanio/torrent-bencode).

When I run my code, bencode_test.php from the command line, the error I get is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'BEncode' not found in /home/user/bencode_test/bencode_test.php on line 3
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > ***Calling a class should be like this***

your folder looks like this

```
bencode_test # calling function from here
            |--> BEncode.php
            |--> bencode_test.php
            |--> ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent
index.php # code
```

So inside BEncode.php

```
public function myName($value)
{
    $name = "My Name is :".$value;
    return $name
}
```

So inside index.php

```
<?php
    require './bencode_test/BEncode.php';
    $bcoder = myName("Ab");
    //$torrent = $bcoder->bdecode( File::get('ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent'));
    //var_dump($torrent);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Abdulla. Can you tell me why the creator used the new operator in his README.md?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655937/what-is-the-difference-between-readme-and-readme-md-in-github-projects

Answer (score 0):

The [file you linked on GitHub](https://github.com/bhutanio/torrent-bencode/blob/master/src/Bhutanio/BEncode/BEncode.php#L3) is in a namespace. You have to add an alias for the class in the beginning of the file::

```
<?php
use Bhutanio\BEncode\BEncode;
?>
```

So in conclusion:

```
<?php
use Bhutanio\BEncode\BEncode;
require 'BEncode.php';
$bcoder = new BEncode();
$torrent = $bcoder->bdecode( File::get('ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent'));
var_dump($torrent);
```

Or if you don't want to add an alias, use the fully qualified class name:

```
<?php
require 'BEncode.php';
$bcoder = new Bhutanio\BEncode\BEncode();
$torrent = $bcoder->bdecode( File::get('ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent'));
var_dump($torrent);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, Pemap.